# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.29.0.. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio

I can't launch my C# project.

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.29.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'. The located assembly's manifest
> definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040) File
> name: 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.29.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'    at
> MySQL_namespace.SQLWork.Initialize(String server_name, String _port,
> String database_name, String user, String pass) ...

It used to work before long time ago. Now, after I had issues with MySQL connection I have updated MySQL connector nuget. After that I also rebuilt it using .Net 5.0. Can't launch it now as it returns above error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows:

1. After deleting the original nuget.
2. Clean the project.
3. Reinstall the new nuget.
4. Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to copy it to the output directory?